# Vaadin Charts and drilldown

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-charts

I have a project where the data in the main chart is represented as a bar chart and the data in a drilldown should be line/area/column chart.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

You can manipulate your logic.
Use the click events on the chart and then open a new window with the new charts you want.

Example of chart click event:
https://demo.vaadin.com/charts/#DateAxisAndClickEvent

Comment: did this help you? if so please check it as answer or vote up!